# what does fd:// mean exactly in dockerd -H fd://

Tags: sockets, docker

[Docker daemon documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) suggests the following `hosts` option for most setups:

```
dockerd -H fd://
```

I guess `fd` stands for file descriptor. I don't understand how `fd` is used for socket communication.

I understand the following options:

```
-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://192.168.59.106 -H tcp://10.10.10.2
```

These are unix domain sockets and tcp sockets. I know how to call docker daemon using these sockets:

```
docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 ps
```

But if I started docker daemon using `-H fd://`, the following call gives error:

```
$ docker -H fd:// ps
error during connect: Get http:///v1.26/containers/json: http: no Host in request URL
```

So what is the meaning of `fd://`? Is there any use for it?

Answer (score 76):

When you start the Docker daemon, `-H fd://` will tell Docker that the service is being started by Systemd and will use socket activation. systemd will then create the target socket and pass it to the Docker daemon to use. This is described in [introduction to Systemd](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd.html) and in [introduction to socket activation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html). The blogs are pretty long but really worth reading, here's a short summary of key points for understanding this question:

- Systemd is a new `init` system intended to replace traditional SysV init system. One of its key features is faster init process.
- `Socket activation` is one of the technologies used in Systemd to speed up service initialization
- To receive requests, the service needs a socket to listen on. Take Docker as an example, it needs a `unix domain socket` like `/var/run/docker.sock` or a TCP socket. Of course these sockets needs something to create them and most of the time it is the service itself at start time.
- With socket activation, SystemD will create these sockets and listen to them for services, and pass these sockets to service with `exec` when the service is started. One benefit is that client requests can be queued in the socket buffer once the socket is successfully created, even before the related service is started.
- The socket info for a certain service used by Systemd is in `socket` unit file, for Docker it's `[docker.socket][3]` with content:

  ```
    [Unit]
    Description=Docker Socket for the API
    PartOf=docker.service

    [Socket]
    ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
    SocketMode=0660
    SocketUser=root
    SocketGroup=docker

    [Install]
    WantedBy=sockets.target
  ```

Let's see how the whole thing works. I have the files `docker.socket` and `docker.service` under `/etc/systemd/system`. The `ExecStart` line for `docker.service` is:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
```

1. Stop Docker service: `systemctl stop docker`

   ```
   $> ps aux | grep 'docker' # the `grep` itself in the output is ignored
   $> lsof -Ua | grep 'docker'
   $>
   ```

   No docker process is running, and no `docker.sock`
2. Execute `systemctl start docker.socket`:

   ```
   $> systemctl start docker.socket
   $> ps aux | grep 'docker' 
   $> lsof -Ua | grep 'docker'
   systemd       1    root   27u  unix 0xffff880036da6000      0t0 140748188 /var/run/docker.sock
   ```

   After start `docker.socket`, we can see that there's still no docker process running, but the socket `/var/run/docker.sock` has been created, and it belongs to the process `systemd`.

   (Off-Topic: Actually the socket is ready to receive requests now, even though `docker` is not running yet. systemd will start `docker.service` at the moment the first request comes, passing the already created sockets to Docker. This is so-called on-demand auto-spawning)
3. Start `docker.service`

   ```
   $> systemctl start docker.service
   $> ps aux | grep 'docker'
   root     26302  0.0  1.8 431036 38712 ?        Ssl  14:57   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
   <....>
   ```

   As you can tell Docker is now running. Let's go one step back and try to execute `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` manually from terminal:

   ```
   $> /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
   FATA[0000] no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd
   ```

   Now you see the difference; when you use `-H fd://`, docker will expect the socket to be passed by its parent process rather than creating it by itself. When it's started by Systemd, Systemd will do the job, but when you manually start it on terminal, you don't do the job so the docker daemon process failed and aborted. This is the [code of how docker process fd:// when docker daemon starts](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/41be7293f54f15dc04f024bf2b0f09e1a697208b/daemon/listeners/listeners_linux.go#L63), you can have a look if you're interested.

On the other hand for the docker client, docker cli will parse protocol/addr from `host` specified in `-H` and make an `http` request to the docker daemon. The default host is `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. The supported protocols include `tcp`, `unix`, `npipe` and `fd`. As far as I explore from source code the transport configuration for `fd` is the same with `tcp` so if you have tcp socket listening, you can just play it with:

```
$> docker -H fd://localhost:4322 ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

which is the same as:

```
docker -H tcp://localhost:4322 ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: Great description @shizhz

Comment: Thanks @Alkaline for improving the answer, English is not my primary language :-

Comment: Nice explanation! This should be in the dockerd man page even though its systemd specific. The only thing I could find is https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

Comment: Thanks for very detailed answer.

Comment: @shizhz FYI the link for "code of how docker process fd:// ..." is now broken.

Comment: @Atralb I updated the link with a more stable one (using the code in a blob instead of `master` which is subject to changes).

Answer (score 5):

The `-H fd://` syntax is used when running docker inside of systemd. Systemd itself will create a socket in the docker.socket unit file and listen to it, and this socket is connected to the docker daemon with the `fd://` syntax in the docker.service unit file.